# How do I make a number within a variable name increase for the length of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, variables

```
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(Active_Member)):
        d["Member_{0}".format(i)] = Active_Member[i]
    print(d)
    for i in range(len(d)):
        (Member_[d]) = (Member_[i](4))
```

Active_Member is already defined and the dictionary has been filled with around 13 values.

I am trying to make each value in the dictionary get put into its own variable but the amount of values that will be in the dictionary can be subject to change and therefore I cannot hard code this.

I am quite new to Python and probably a bit over me head however any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need variables when you already have everything in a dict?

Comment: Also why are you using a dict? just use a list and access by index since your member names are `Member_0`, `Member_1`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

say we have a dictionary like

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
```

we can iterate over all of the dictionary keys and make them variables with there respective values by doing

```
for key,val in dictionary.items():
    exec(key + '=val')
```

Hope that helps!